# CSS Menu Not Positioning Correctly, All lists of menus shows under first menu

Tags: html, css

i cant post all of my code, so please check the url.

http://www.bierhauschina.com/shekou/kulinarium/
here is css:
http://www.bierhauschina.com/menu/menu_style.css

The problem is a css menu. my menu shows all lists of menu under the first menu. i don't know where is problem, but it is exactly in css. where.. i can't got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `position: relative;` to `.nav .select, .nav .current`, making it like this:

```
.nav .select, .nav .current {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: table-cell;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `position: relative` to `.nav li` in your CSS.

Comment: thankyou @nheinrich for 1st correct answer, but it hides my all menu text. but anyway thankyou for your answer.

Comment: You're right, it needs to be applied to both .select and .current. I tested it in the web inspector but must have made a mistake. I'm glad you ended up with the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

This style:

```
.nav .select *:hover .select_sub, .nav .current .show
```

Sets position to absolute.  Set it to relative.  Also you are loading menu_style.css twice, remove the second reference.